# Displaying numbers with "X" instead of "e" scientific notation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, I would like to write text on my plots that displays in normal scientific notation, for example, as 1.92x10<sup>-7</sup> instead of the default 1.92e-7.  I have found help on how to do this for numbers labeling ticks on the axes but not for the text function.  Here is an example of my code that I would like to change:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,0.5)
y = x*(1.0-x)

a=1.92e-7

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.text(0.01, 0.23, r"$a = {0:0.2e}$".format(a), size=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: First idea would be a filter function, which transforms the output of the format method. Is this sufficient already, and if not, why? And otherwise: Strictly scientific notation would be a middle dot instead of a "x"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slightly hacky way of doing this is to build your own tex string for the number from its Python string representation. Pass `as_si`, defined below, your number and a number of decimal places and it will produce this tex string:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,0.5)
y = x*(1.0-x)

def as_si(x, ndp):
    s = '{x:0.{ndp:d}e}'.format(x=x, ndp=ndp)
    m, e = s.split('e')
    return r'{m:s}\times 10^{{{e:d}}}'.format(m=m, e=int(e))

a=1.92e-7

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.text(0.01, 0.23, r"$a = {0:s}$".format(as_si(a,2)), size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is less hacky and more versitile than the method I came up with.  However, I don't understand why 3 nested braces are needed to format the exponent.  I also don't understand why its "`format(m=m, e=int(e))`" and not "`format(m, int(e))`".

Comment: You need a single pair of braces in the TeX output and a single literal brace is obtained by doubling-up (`{{` and `}}`) in a new-style Python formatted string; named (keyword) format specifiers are an alternative to listing them in the `format` function.